# how to open blackberry "Files" application by code?

Tags: blackberry, invoke

Now I can use *Invoke.invokeApplication()* to invoke a system application in blackberry, such as Messages, Calendar, etc.

however, I don't know how to launch "Files" application, which managers files of blackberry smartphone, and locate to a desired path.

could you kindly give me an answer? thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a [link](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/11935/Create_new_blank_sms_text_msg_565423_11.jsp) that describes how to invoke a BlackBerry® Device Software application, such as the contacts application, the phone application, and the media application.

Comment: the demo shows how to open SMS application, using Invoke.APP_TYPE_MESSAGES constant. but I can't find anything like Invoke.APP_TYPE_FILES in the Inoke API references. thank u all the same.

Comment: read the doc from starting you will get all the needful information ..everything is fully explained with example