# How to invoke applications on BlackBerry

Tags: java, blackberry

I'm new on this world of BlackBerry and the thing is that i have a byte array of certain file that can be anything (picture, pdf, txt ...) and need to be shown. How can i execute applications related with the specific extention? In other words how can i invoke an application and give it the byte array to be displayed as the original file?
I also have the extention or file type.
I have tried to open the file using browsers but it always return timeout and that's not the idea.
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12987826/how-to-open-blackberry-files-application-by-code) is something like my question but it has not a final response. I'm developing for BlackBerry Curve.

Comment: Are you developing for the BB10 or BBOS phones?

Comment: I'm using a BlackBerry Curve simulator.

Answer (score 0):

I have never used it, but I think the appropriate API for this is the Content Handler API, most commonly referred to as CHAPI I think.  Look for documentation of javax.microedition.content. Here is a link that will take you to the [ContentHandler](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.1.0api/javax/microedition/content/ContentHandler.html) class.

I suggest that you look for the chapidemo sample for more information.  It should have come with your tooling, if not, here it is on github: [chapidemo sample](https://github.com/blackberry/JDE-Samples/tree/master/com/rim/samples/device/chapidemo).